# Проблема отображения текста (Label) на форме при использовании TransparencyKey

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть необходимость в создании прозрачного фона формы, на которой находится текст.

Я изменил цвет формы на Magenta, тот же цвет указал и в параметре формы TransparencyKey. Затем я создал текст Label, запустил программу, но вот незадача: на границе букв появляется окантовка цвета мадженты. То есть она видна только на фоне цвета отличного от мадженты

Один и тот же текст на разных фонах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить эту окантовку или есть другой метод создания прозрачного окна с отсутствием такой проблемы?

Comment: Вам принципиально использовать [tag:winforms]?

Comment: Да, хотелось бы именно winforms.

Comment: Весьма похоже на проблему сглаживания шрифтов: на границе между меткой и фоном формы выполняется интерполяция цветов, между "Magenta" и цветом текста. У меня проблема исчезла, когда в свойствах метки поставил свойство [UseCompatibleTextRendering](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.usecompatibletextrendering?view=netframework-4.7.1) в значение "True". Ответом не оформляю, т.к. не знаю, всегда ли результат будет именно таким.

Comment: Увы, проблема осталась после установки этого параметра